# Google Earth Engine - Get Image with lowest NDVI from a time period

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, maximum

One of the answers to this question ([Google Earth Engine - Get Image with highest max Scene NDVI from a time period](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362141/google-earth-engine-get-image-with-highest-max-scene-ndvi-from-a-time-period?rq=1)) provides code which gives a Sentinel image/date with the highest NDVI for each region (https://code.earthengine.google.com/5165eca22f5dbfc8e114919d9315ab73).

This is half of what I want, but I also want the Sentinel image/date of the lowest NDVI for a region, but am not sure how. I have tried changing

```
return ee.Feature(meanFeatureCollection.sort('mean').first()
```

to descending order, but it didn't change the console output.

EDIT: I double checked and the link code doesn't actually do as described, it only prints the NDVI and ID of first Sentinel image in the collection. So I also need the correct script to identify highest AND lowest NDVI images.

Comment: In the code provided as an answer to the question you referred to,
https://code.earthengine.google.com/013a113d3f01c192ff7370d236197a8a
For lowest value, just change to .aggregate_min('mean') in the 

var highestMean = mosaicsWithMean.aggregate_max('mean')

Comment: thank you very much. if you want to post this as answer, i'll accept it. either way thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/013a113d3f01c192ff7370d236197a8a), the code provided as an answer to the question you referred to.
For getting lowest value, you can change max to min

```
var highestMean = mosaicsWithMean.aggregate_max('mean')
```

to

```
var lowestMean = mosaicsWithMean.aggregate_min('mean')
```

Comment: thanks so much. I also want to turn all negative ndvi values used in the calculations to 0, but I can't figure out what/how to alter this code