# GEE NDVI function that removes negative values

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi

Within my NDVI function, I want to either reclassify negative values (-1 to 0) as 0, or change them into 'no data'. Specifically, I want to the do this calculation/reclassification in the code provided in response to this question: [Google Earth Engine - Get Image with highest max Scene NDVI from a time period](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362141/google-earth-engine-get-image-with-highest-max-scene-ndvi-from-a-time-period?rq=1).

I suspect I need to alter the NDVI function, but so far any changes have given me error messages or inhibit the previous functions.

```
function toNdvi(image) {
  return image
    .normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
    .rename('ndvi')
    .updateMask(
      image.select('QA60').not()
    )}
```

Code in question found here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/013a113d3f01c192ff7370d236197a8a

Comment: You are missing a closing curly brace `}` from your function, is that just a typo?

Comment: sorry yeah typo, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mask the unwanted values directly in the same function using `updateMask`.

```
function toNdvi(image) {
  var newImg = image
    .normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4'])
    .rename('ndvi')
    .updateMask(
      image.select('QA60').not()
    )
    return newImg.updateMask(
      newImg.select('ndvi').gte(0)
    )
```

}

Comment: thank you for your response. this addition gives me the error message: 'Image.select: Pattern 'ndvi' did not match any bands'. i have updated the question.

Comment: This solution is almost there.  but slightly wrong.  Do not try to return in one go but make a variable and then return using the second updateMask and it will work.  I've edited the code as per.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that detail. Thanks for the edit.